# Google's Big Query using SQL: Associate the assignee name and harmonized assignee name when there are multiple assignees

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My goal is to create a table from Google's Big Query patents-public-data.patents.publications_201710 table using standard SQL that has one row for the publication_number, assignee and assignee_harmonized.name where the publication_number is repeated for records that have multiple assignees. Here's an example of my desired output:

publication_number|assignee|assignee_harm

US-6044964-A|Sony Corporation|SONY CORP

US-6044964-A|Digital Audio Disc Corporation|DIGITAL AUDIO DISC CORP

US-8746747-B2|IPS Corporation—Weld-On Division|IPS CORPORATION—WELD ON DIVISION

US-8746747-B2|null|MCPHERSON TERRY R

I've tried the following query based off of the UNNEST suggestion found in [this post](https://www.ificlaims.com/news/view/blog-posts/public-patent-data-now.htm)

```
#standard SQL
SELECT
  p.publication_number,
  p.assignee,
  a.name AS assignee_harm
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications_201710` AS p,
  UNNEST(assignee_harmonized) AS a
WHERE
  p.publication_number IN ('US-6044964-A',
    'US-8746747-B2')
```

However, the output appears as follows:

row|publication_number|assignee|assignee_harm

1|US-6044964-A|Sony Corporation|SONY CORP

||Digital Audio Disc Corporation|

2|US-6044964-A|Sony Corporation|DIGITAL AUDIO DISC CORP

||Digital Audio Disc Corporation|

3|US-8746747-B2|IPS Corporation—Weld-On Division|MCPHERSON TERRY R

4|US-8746747-B2|IPS Corporation—Weld-On Division|IPS CORPORATION—WELD ON DIVISION

You can see that the "Sony Corporation" assignee is inappropriately associated with the "DIGITAL AUDIO DISC CORP" harmonized name in row 2 with a similar issue appearing in row 3. Also, rows 1 and 2 contain two lines each but don't repeat the publication_number identifier. I don't see a straightforward way to do this because the number of "assignee" doesn't always equal the number of "assignee_harmonized.name" and they don't always appear in the same order (otherwise I could try creating two tables and merging them somehow). On the other hand, there has to be a way to associate the "assignee" variable with its harmonized value "assignee_harmonized.name", otherwise the purpose of having a harmonized value is lost. Could you please suggest a query (or set of queries) that will produce the desired output when there are either multiple "assignee" or multiple "assignee_harmonized.name" or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying for a string and two arrays - the whole thing basically looks like this:

```
  {
    "publication_number": "US-8746747-B2",
    "assignee": [
      "IPS Corporation—Weld-On Division"
    ],
    "assignee_harm": [
      "MCPHERSON TERRY R",
      "IPS CORPORATION—WELD ON DIVISION"
    ]
  }
```

So that's the data and you somehow need to decide how to treat the combination of them ... either you cross join everything:

```
#standard SQL
SELECT
  p.publication_number,
  assignee,
  assignee_harmonized.name  AS assignee_harm
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications_201710` AS p
  ,p.assignee assignee
  ,p.assignee_harmonized AS assignee_harmonized
WHERE
  p.publication_number IN ('US-6044964-A','US-8746747-B2')
```

.. which gives you relational data .. or you leave it as two separate arrays:

```
#standard SQL
SELECT
  p.publication_number,
  assignee,
  ARRAY( (SELECT name FROM p.assignee_harmonized)) AS assignee_harm
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications_201710` AS p
WHERE
  p.publication_number IN ('US-6044964-A','US-8746747-B2')
```

You can save this nested result as a table in bq as well.